# JavaScript passing variables between functions to target an object in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, nested, javascript-objects

(Warning) First post, doing my best here. Sorry in advance if get the format wrong.

I am creating a simple crypto currency converter following these instructions:

*Define a function called 'addCurrency' which takes 3 arguments: a 'coin' a 'value' and an array ('crypt')

Inside use Array.prototype.findIndex to see if the 'coin' is already present in the 'crypt' array. storing the index if you find it.

if it is NOT:
push it to the 'crypt' array.
then return a string as the one below replacing the word COIN with the name of the 'coin' you added (capitalize).

If it is there, call 'findCurrency' to get the rate.

Define a function called 'findCurrency' which takes 3 arguments: a 'coin' a 'value' an index (from 'addCurrency') and the 'crypt' array.
get the rate of the 'coin' using the index to access the right 'coin' from the 'crypt' array.

call the converter function passing the 'value', the rate and the 'coin'.
Define a function called converter which takes 3 arguments, a 'value' a rate and a 'coin'.

Perform the conversion and return call tellConversion to output the result.
Define a function called tellConversion which takes 3 arguments a result, a 'coin' and a 'value'.

Create a string as shown in the example using the arguments of tellConversion.*

Running the code below in the console, I get:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'rate' of undefined

at this line --> `var coinRate = crypt[coinIndex].rate;`

coinIndex logs out to the console and crypt is passed in the initial function call. Why is var coinRate undefined?

What am I missing?

```
var addCurrency = (coinObj, value, crypt) => {
    
    function findCurrency(crypt, coinIndex, value){
-->     var coinRate = crypt[coinIndex].rate;
        console.log(coinRate)
        converter(value, coinRate)
    }
            
    function converter(value, coinRate){
      var converted = coinRate * value;
        console.log(converted)
        tellConversion(value, converted, coinObj)
    }
    function tellConversion(value, converted, coinObj){
      return `You will receive ${converted} usd for your ${value} ${coinObj.coin}`
    }

    var coinIndex = crypt.findIndex(obj => obj.coin === coinObj.coin)
        console.log(coinIndex)
        if(coinIndex === -1){
            crypt.push(coinObj)
            console.log(crypt)
            return `New coin ${coinObj.coin.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + coinObj.coin.slice(1)} added to Database`
            
        } else { findCurrency(value, coinIndex, coinObj) }
        
  }
```

calling the function:

```
var crypt = [{coin:'eth', rate:800}]
addCurrency({coin:'eth', rate:800}, 2, crypt)
```

Comment: I didn't look at everything but when you call tellConversion from converter, the return value is lost, because converter doesn't return anything, if that makes any sense.

Answer (score 0):

The order of passing the params is incorrect to `findCurrency` function.

Update the `findCurrency` function to accept just the `coinIndex` as an argument.

```js
function findCurrency(coinIndex){
  var coinRate = crypt[coinIndex].rate;
  console.log(coinRate)
  converter(value, coinRate)
}
```

`value` and `crypt` variables will be available inside the `findCurrency` as they are in the same scope.

Overall Code:

```js
var addCurrency = (coinObj, value, crypt) => {
    
  function findCurrency(coinIndex){

     var coinRate = crypt[coinIndex].rate;
      console.log(coinRate)
      converter(value, coinRate)
  }
          
  function converter(value, coinRate){
    var converted = coinRate * value;
      console.log(converted)
      tellConversion(value, converted, coinObj)
  }
  function tellConversion(value, converted, coinObj){
    return `You will receive ${converted} usd for your ${value} ${coinObj.coin}`
  }

  var coinIndex = crypt.findIndex(obj => obj.coin === coinObj.coin)
      console.log(coinIndex)
      if(coinIndex === -1){
          crypt.push(coinObj)
          console.log(crypt)
          return `New coin ${coinObj.coin.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + coinObj.coin.slice(1)} added to Database`
          
      } else { findCurrency(coinIndex) }
      
}

var crypt = [{coin:'eth', rate:800}]
addCurrency({coin:'eth', rate:800}, 2, crypt)
```

Comment: I made the changes above and now it works all the way to `var coinRate = crypt[coinIndex].rate;
      console.log(coinRate)`  but for some reason does not execute the function call:  `converter(value, coinRate)`